# Orthogonal matrix with eigenvalues $\in \mathbb{R}$ is symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices, orthogonal-matrices

I need help showing that an orthogonal matrix with all real eigenvalues is symmetric. 
The condition for Orthogonality is.
$$O^T = O^{-1} \implies O^TO = I$$

But if O is also symmetric:

$$O^T = O = O^{-1}$$

I have tried using the similarity transform relationship:

$$S^{-1}OS = D = diag(\lambda_i) \implies (S^{-1}OS)^T = S^TO^{-1}S^{-1^T} = D$$

I don't really understand where the idea of real eigenvalues comes in other than the fact that symmetric matrices have all real eigen values. I'm not quite sure how to prove what I want to show without explicitly using it.

Comment: You can actually take $S$ to be unitary.

Comment: Related to: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/913093/497335

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint 1: An orthogonal matrix is normal.

Hint 2: Every normal matrix is diagonalizable via a unitary matrix (this is actually a characterization of normality).

Hint 3: Prove the result for a  normal matrix.

Hint 4: The answer is somewhere here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix in the form of a characterization of self-adjoint matrices.

Comment: You're welcome.