# A normal matrix with real eigenvalues is Hermitian

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, hermitian-matrices

$A$ is a normal matrix (i.e. $AA^*=A^*A$, where * denotes the hermitian conjugate). If all its eigenvalues are real, prove that it is Hermitian (i.e. $A^*=A$).

I have tried many things but could not complete a proof.
Could anybody please provide some help?

Comment: @amcalde The definition of a normal matrix is that it commutes with its conjugate transpose: $AA^*=A^*A$. This doesn't necessarily mean that a normal matrix equals its conjugate transpose.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A matrix $A$ is normal if and only it is diagonalized by some unitary matrix, i.e., there exists a unitary matrix $U$ ($UU^*=U^*U=I$), such that
$$
A=U^*DU,
$$
with $D$ diagonal, containing the eigenvalues of $A$ in the diagonal. (See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix).)

In our case the eigenvalues of $A$ are real. Then
$$
A^*=(U^*DU)^*=U^*D^*U=U^*DU=A,
$$
as $D^*=D$, since the eigenvalues are real.