# Showing that a normal matrix with real eigenvalues is Hermitian. A question about properties orthonormal matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, operator-theory, orthogonality, orthonormal

This problem is part of exercise 2.17 in Nielsen and Chuang's textbook, and has been already answered on this site in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/913093/a-normal-matrix-with-real-eigenvalues-is-hermitian) post.

I understand that because $A$ is normal, it can be orthogonally diagonalized

\begin{equation}
A = U^*DU
\end{equation}

where $U$ is orthonormal.

What I do not understand is the claim that $U^*U = UU^* = I$, where $^*$ denotes conjugate-transpose. I know that orthonormal matrices satisfy $UU^T = I$, where $^T$ is transpose. But if $U$ has complex entries, then conjugate-transpose should not in general equal transpose alone.

Answer (score 1):

You are mistaken when you write that “because $A$ is normal, it can be orthogonally diagonalized $A=U^∗DU$, where $U$ is orthonormal.” Being normal is equivalent to the assertion that $A$ is *unitarily* diagonalizable.